# Flask handle multiple users and app termination

Tags: python, flask, pythonanywhere

I have a flask application that contains a chatbot, deployed successfully on pythonanywhere.com but the problem is it serves one user only. I tried the code below but did not work.

```
app.run(threaded=True)
```

(EDIT): Here is the route of the home page where the chatbot exist

```
@app.route('/bhome')
def Bhome():
    if session['logged_in'] == False:  
        return render_template('Login.html')
        user = session['username']
        return render_template('b/home.html')
```

The other problem I have is when the user refreshes the page the chat should be terminated and start over again but it doesn't, how can I fix that?

Comment: show us code of routes

Comment: what do you mean it serves one user only?

Comment: If indentation in your example is the same as in your code, the two last lines will never be executed, and a template will only be returned for non logged users

Comment: @LaLa I read your post on pythonanywhere as well. Could you get a solution of the problem?